# Programmatically setting semibold font prior to iOS 8.2

Tags: ios, uifont

I understand that semibold system font can be set with `UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)`. I also have some labels set with system font semibold in the IB. What font will iOS use from the interface builder instead for system semibold (San Fransisco) if it is not available? Will it use system bold or just regular?

```
if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
  choiceLetterLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
  } else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    choiceLetterLabel.font = choiceLetterLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
  }
```

Is the code above correct? I want it to match interface builders fallback, bold or regular?

thanks!